# Using Ruby for platform-independent application

Tags: ruby

I want to write a desktop application using Ruby. I want it platform-independent and with rich GUI. How to start? What tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with [wxRuby](http://wxruby.rubyforge.org/)

[Tutorials](http://wxruby.rubyforge.org/wiki/wiki.pl?WxRuby_Tutorial)

Hello World

```
require "wx"
 include Wx

 class HelloWorld < App

   def on_init  

     helloframe = Frame.new(nil, -1, "Hello World")

     StaticText.new(helloframe,-1,"Hello World")

     helloframe.show()
   end
 end

 HelloWorld.new.main_loop
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [Shoes](http://github.com/shoes/shoes).

```
Shoes.app do
  button "Press me" do
    alert "You pressed me"
  end
end
```

You could also try [FXRuby](http://www.fxruby.org/). [PragProg has a book on it.](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/fxruby/fxruby)

Comment: I wanted to do this for Windows, Mac and Linux, but ran into issues getting shoes working on all three.  It has a custom ruby build, which complicates things.  I don't know if wxRuby is better.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first consider [QtRuby](http://rubyforge.org/projects/korundum/). There's a nice tutorial on making it work for Windows [here](http://tom.paschenda.org/blog/?p=38). I think Qt has the edge over wxWidgets in providing nice looking GUI's on [OS/X](http://qt.nokia.com/products/platform/qt-for-mac).